# Is there anything connecting concrete connecting evaluating of non perturbative field theory correlation functions and solitons/instantons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I keep reading about instantons and solitons being non-perturbative effects. Well it does make sense that mass of solitons goes inversly as coupling constants so their effects would not be seen in perturbation theory. But I am curious about non perturbative field theory. Is it that at higher values of gauge coupling the field theory is necessarily dual to another theory made up of solitons interacting with each other at a lower value of gauge coupling